# How do I pass a string of symbols for bquote to evaluate in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The axis labels vary for a ggplot that I create within a function.  Some of the labels have super/subscripts, while others don't.  Example:

```
  m.data <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))
  x.labs <- c("rain, mm", "light*','~W~m^-2")  
  for (i in 1:2) {
     ggplot(m.data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        labs(title = bquote(.(x.labs[i])))
  }
```

The title for the graph when i=2 is literally

light*','~W~m^-2

rather than the formatted version of same.  With the same result, I also tried moving bquote inside each string.

```
 x.labs <- c("bquote(rain*','~mm)", "bquote(light*','~W~m^-2)")
```

and

```
 title = x.labs[i]
```

Of the many questions about ggplot and bquote, none seem to address passing in a symbol like the superscript indicator.

Comment: Maybe something like `expression("light,"~W~m^-2)` in `xlabs`?

Comment: If you would like to post that as a [very short] answer, I'd be pleased to accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use `expression()` in your vector of titles instead of `bquote()`.

For example

```
x.labs <- c("rain, mm", expression("light,"~W~m^-2))

ggplot(m.data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    labs(title = x.labs[2])
```

[image]